# finding nth term in a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

There are $1065$ seats in an auditorium. The first row has $21$ seats and the next row has $1$ more seats than the first row and goes on to the others. How many rows are there in the auditorium ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common difference is $1\implies$ we are talking about Arithmetic Series

We know the sum for $n$ consecutive terms $=\dfrac n2\{2\cdot21+(n-1)1\}$

Comment: I was having a problem at solving that equation

Answer (score 1):

Let there be $n$ number of rows having seats in increasing order  then the total number of seats in the auditorium $$1065=\underbrace{21+22+23+24+\ldots+\text{up to n times}}_{\text{n number of rows}}$$
$$1065=\text{sum of A.P. having 'n' terms with first term a=21 & common difference d=1 }$$ $$1065=\frac{n}{2}(2a+(n-1)d)$$
$$\frac{n}{2}(2(21)+(n-1)1)=1065$$ $$n^2+41n-2130=0$$ On solving above quadratic equation for $n$, we get $$n=\frac{-41\pm\sqrt{41^2-4(1)(-2130)}}{2(1)}$$ 
$$=\frac{-41\pm101}{2}$$  $$n=30, -71$$ But, $n>0$ Hence, we have 
$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\text{Total number of seats}=30}}$$

Comment: Without knowing the Arithmetic Series formula you used, we can get the answer as follows: Write the sum once, and again in reverse order, then add the two, noting that corresponding terms all add to $41+n$:
$$\begin{align}
21 \quad &+ \quad (21+1)\quad &+\quad \cdots\quad &+\quad 21+(n-1)\\
21+(n-1)\quad &+\quad 21 +(n-2)\quad &+\quad \cdots\quad &+\quad 21\\
\hline\\
41+n\quad &+ \quad 41+n\quad &+\quad \cdots\quad &+\quad 41+n\quad\quad\quad\quad=n(41+n)
\end{align}$$

Thus $n$ is the solution to $\frac{n(41+n)}{2} = 1065$, i.e., $n^2+41n-2130=0$.